# Окружность в виде воздушного шарика

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Вот мой текущий код `CSS` для окружности:

```
.circle-image{
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url("/assets/img/dashboard/img-stdn.png");
    display: block;
}
```

И вывод `div`, как показано ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу изменить границу `div`, чтобы сделать его таким?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пусть это изображение будет размещено внутри `div`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Circle div balloon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30523176/7394871) от участника  [@Nere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4310083/nere).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523176/circle-div-balloon/30525231#30525231

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать псевдо-элемент для того, чтобы создать свой пузырь с треугольником, как показано в демо ниже.

Это работает с использованием `skew` на квадрат и абсолютно позиционирует его  внутри относительно позиционированного элемента контейнера.

Альтернативно, это может быть достигнуто с помощью одного элемента, если бы вы могли использовать `background-image` вместо тега `<image>`.

```css
.circ {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bordeR: 5px solid tomato;
  position: relative;
}
.circ img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.circ:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:10%;
  right:0;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  background:tomato;
  transform:skewX(55deg) skewY(10deg);
  }
```

```html
<div class="circ">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCp2t.png" />
</div>
```

Для получения дополнительной информации по генерации треугольника, вы можете использовать [эту](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299093/speech-bubble-with-arrow) весьма полезную демонстрацию того, как реализовать этот треугольник.

### Background-image

Вместо этого, используя фоновое изображение, вы можете сделать это только с одним элементом.

```css
.circ {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;  
  border: 5px solid tomato;
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCp2t.png);
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
.circ:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:10%;
  right:0;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  background:tomato;
  transform:skewX(55deg) skewY(10deg);
  z-index:-1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="circ"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Circle div balloon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30525231/7394871) от участника  [@jbutler483](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3436942/jbutler483).</sub>